# How do you create a crossfade transition between multiple videos in FFMPEG?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, transition, blend, smoothing

I am currently looping MP4 videos with audio through FFMPEG. Here is the code

```
del intermediate1.ts
del f.txt
echo file intermediate1.ts>f.txt
echo file intermediate1.ts>>f.txt
echo file intermediate1.ts>>f.txt
echo file intermediate1.ts>>f.txt
echo file intermediate1.ts>>f.txt
echo file intermediate1.ts>>f.txt
echo file intermediate1.ts>>f.txt
echo file intermediate1.ts>>f.txt
echo file intermediate1.ts>>f.txt
echo file intermediate1.ts>>f.txt
echo file intermediate1.ts>>f.txt
echo file intermediate1.ts>>f.txt
echo file intermediate1.ts>>f.txt
echo file intermediate1.ts>>f.txt
echo file intermediate1.ts>>f.txt
echo file intermediate1.ts>>f.txt
echo file intermediate1.ts>>f.txt

ffmpeg -i "SHORT MUSIC.mp4" -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate1.ts -nostdin
ffmpeg -f concat -i f.txt -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc "LONG MUSIC.mp4" -nostdin
```

However, the transition between each instance of the videos is not smooth. It cuts off as the next instance is shown. Would there be a way create a blend/crossfade transition for the videos?

I have come across this method however, it is only for 2 videos 
https://superuser.com/questions/778762/crossfade-between-2-videos-using-ffmpeg

Hope someone can help me!
Thank you very much!!

Comment: [Crosspost](http://superuser.com/questions/1021964/how-do-you-create-a-crossfade-transition-between-multiple-videos-in-ffmpeg)