# Combining videos with ffmpeg using crossfades and plain cuts

Tags: linux, video, scripting, ffmpeg, video-editing

I am writing a script to combine/slice arbitrary video files from S3 into one output video. So far, I am doing this by first trimming the videos to their proper length using `ffmpeg -i input-X.mp4 -ss start -t duration slice-X.mp4` and recombining the resultant slices with the ffmpeg `concat` filter.

I want to be able to crossfade and cut between videos. `concat` does not support transitions. What is the best way to combine videos with crossfades and cuts on the Linux command line? Is ffmpeg the best tool for the job?

My question is similar to ["How do you create a crossfade transition between multiple videos in FFMPEG?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34606097/how-do-you-create-a-crossfade-transition-between-multiple-videos-in-ffmpeg) but I do not necessarily need to use ffmpeg. Also, I want to be able to fade in between some slices and cut between others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is the single step command template, assuming five slices.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i input.mp4 -i input.mp4 -i input.mp4 -i input.mp4 \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]trim=0.5:4.5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[1]; \
 [1:v]trim=12:17,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(3/TB),format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=3:d=1:alpha=1[2]; \
 [2:v]trim=34.1:36,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(7/TB),format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=7:d=1:alpha=1[3]; \
 [3:v]trim=21:25,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[4]; \
 [4:v]trim=27:31,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(3/TB),format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[5]; \
 [0:a]atrim=0.5:4.5,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[1a]; \
 [1:a]atrim=12:17,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[2a]; \
 [2:a]atrim=34.1:36,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[3a]; \
 [3:a]atrim=21:25,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[4a]; \
 [4:a]atrim=27:31,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[5a]; \
 [1][2]overlay,format=yuv420p[12]; \
 [12][3]overlay,format=yuv420p[123]; \
 [4][5]overlay,format=yuv420p[45]; \
 [1a][2a]acrossfade=d=1[12a]; \
 [12a][3a]acrossfade=d=1[123a]; \
 [4a][5a]acrossfade=d=1[45a]; \
 [123][123a][45][45a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" \
-map [v] -map [a] SingleStepOutput.mp4
```

I have inputted the video multiple times, once for each slice, because using a single input pad (even with `split`/`asplit`) leads to buffer overflows.

The `setpts`/`asetpts` filters are used because `trim`/`atrim` carry over the original timestamps. The `setpts` filters are offset for the slices which have to fade in. The offset value is the `preceding slide duration - crossfade duration`. The `yuva420p` is needed to create an alpha channel whose value is actually modulated by the fade filter.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this by iterating on each slice and appending each to a temporary output file.

> [output] <-- copy slice 1
>   [output] <-- cut slice 2 on to output
>   [output][slice 2] <-- fade slice 3 on to output
>   [output][slice 2][crossfade][slice 3] <-- fade slice 4 on to output, etc...

So it's *n* ffmpeg instructions to slice the input videos to the correct length, and then *n-1* ffmpeg instructions to concatenate them all with appropriate transitions.

Comment: You are re-encoding the video a lot. You could do this in one, albeit long, command. If you're interested, I'll write it up in the next couple of days.

Comment: @Mulvya I'd be interested to see that abomination yeah